# 3D printing using OctoPrint on Linux Ubuntu desktop

Tags: desktop-printer, octoprint

I'm trying to set up [OctoPrint](http://octoprint.org/) on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 desktop to work with my Micro3D printer. The printer works fine on Mac and Windows:
[image]

I've installed OctoPrint with the [M3D Fio Plugin Manager](https://github.com/donovan6000/M3D-Fio). I can see the files in `~/.octoprint/` fine and I can even turn the printer fan on/off, move the extruder, etc. through OctoPrint:
[image]

But when I press the blue "Print button", there is no response. Also the files in the "upload" section are greyed out. Must I download a slicing program or something? I'm new with 3D printing in general but not with Linux. Grateful for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just discovered that OctoPrint only reads .gcode files for printing (apparently, unless you have a slicing software embedded in it), so I installed [Slic3r](http://slic3r.org/download) separately, and ran

```
./slic3r mystlfile.stl
```

to generate a .gcode file (in the executable directory).

Then I uploaded the .gcode file to OctoPrint and things got moving.

Answer (score 2):

For me it sounds like you've missed to install the CuraEngine for slicing, but I'm only guessing, as I'm not using OctoPrint at all.

Instead I'm using Cura directly and save gcode to a SD or use USB printing for quick/small prints.

Regrads ;)

Comment: Yeah I think it comes auto-installed on other systems but not in my case

Comment: On Ubuntu you can install it easily via APT. It is available in the Ubuntu repositories. Additionally it is possible that you'll need a specific version of the engine. You'll find a repository for it on OctoPrint github page.

Comment: Ah, and if you like to use Cura (incl. CuraEngine) provided by Ultimaker you can take a look at my PPA (https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/cura). Remember, that it might be possible that the newer CuraEngine there does not work with OctoPrint.

Comment: I'm now using CuraEngine slicer with the M3D plugin on OctoPrint. Works great. Thanks for suggestion. Yeah there is a limit on supported version of cura.